# What kind of problems will I have re-installing Windows 8.1 64bit OEM when I upgrade my computer?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-installation

I received a copy of `Windows 8.1 64bit OEM` for Christmas.  Notice it's the `OEM` version.

Anyway, I am currently building a new PC that I want to use my new Windows on.  The only thing I need to get a minimum PC running is a new CPU and RAM.

So, once I purchase those parts, I intend to build the PC and install my new Windows.

Now, later on, I want to slowly start upgrading various other parts of the PC starting with replacing the 7200 RPM spinning drive with an SSD one.  Which means a clean install.

Next, I will upgrade my graphics card, upgrade i3 CPU to i7, add new RAM, etc.

Most of the upgrades shouldn't require a clean install.  But if they do (or I simply choose to do so), what kind of issues can I expect considering I have an OEM copy?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be required to reactivate. I added a dvd drive to a windows computer not to long ago and I had to reactive

Comment: Seriously?  That's insane.  When are these companies going to learn that kind of behavior is ridiculous and only annoys legitimate users?

Comment: Yes its crazy, but it said i had significantly changes my hardware so need to be reactivated. i could use the activation stuff in windows either i had to call up and get a code from them.

Comment: Well I guess someone should vote to close this question because apparently it's too broad (and I assume not useful) to anyone who just spent ~$100 for software they are unsure about installing.  +1 anyway...